# Neo4jclient where is this class - Neo4jDataRepository?

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am trying to batch insert relationships into neo4j database using the Neo4jclient for c#.  I found this code by user [dcinzona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120741/dcinzona?tab=summary).  I am looking through the latest source code and can't find this class Neo4jDataRespository anywhere.  Is this a custom class created by this user or am I missing something?

```
string merge1 = string.Format("c:{0} {{{1}:row.{2}}}", IDFieldLeft.Replace("Id", ""), IDFieldLeft, IDFieldLeft);
    string merge2 = string.Format("a:{0} {{{1}:row.{2}}}", IDFieldRight.Replace("Id", ""), IDFieldRight, IDFieldRight);
    string merge3 = string.Format("(c)-[r:{0} {{row}}]->(a)", entityName);
    foreach (var list in Neo4jDataRepository.Batch(relationshipMatrix, 1000))
    {
        var query = client
                    .Cypher
                    .WithParam("coll", list.ToList())
                    .ForEach("(row in {coll})")//manually create json array of list objects
                    .Merge(merge1)
                    .Merge(merge2)
                    .Merge(merge3);
        query.ExecuteWithoutResults();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a custom class created by that user, it's not part of `Neo4jClient`.

I'm not sure what they've done, and I've not seen it referenced anywhere else but by them I'm afraid :/